# Beautiful soup looping through Urls and displaying data

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using Beautiful soup to scrape this url
http://www.gbgb.org.uk/resultsRace.aspx?id=1839041 and it works fine for  displaying all the fields as required.However it only displays one race on the fixture results card,and I would like to extract the entire race meetings,which varies between 9 and 14 races on the card Here is the Url for a whole meeting http://www.gbgb.org.uk/resultsMeeting.aspx?id=135488.
Is there some way I could loop through,the full race card and display the contents of all races on the card.Below is the code for the one race.

```
 from urllib import urlopen

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urlopen("http://www.gbgb.org.uk/resultsRace.aspx?id=1839041")

bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)
nameList = bsObj. findAll("div", {"class": "track"})
for name in nameList:
 print(name. get_text())

nameList = bsObj. findAll("div", {"class": "date"})
for name in nameList:
 print(name. get_text())

nameList = bsObj. findAll("div", {"class": "datetime"})
for name in nameList:
 print(name. get_text())
nameList = bsObj. findAll("div", {"class": "grade"})
for name in nameList:
 print(name. get_text())
nameList = bsObj. findAll("div", {"class": "distance"})
for name in nameList:
 print(name. get_text())
nameList = bsObj. findAll("div", {"class": "prizes"})
for name in nameList:
 print(name. get_text())
nameList = bsObj. findAll("li", {"class": "first essential fin"}) 
for name in nameList:
 print(name. get_text())
nameList = bsObj. findAll("li", {"class": "essential greyhound"})
for name in nameList:
 print(name. get_text())
nameList = bsObj. findAll("li", {"class": "trap"})
for name in nameList:
 print(name. get_text())
nameList = bsObj. findAll("li", {"class": "sp"})
for name in nameList:
 print(name. get_text())
nameList = bsObj. findAll("li", {"class": "timeSec"})
for name in nameList:
 print(name. get_text())
nameList = bsObj. findAll("li", {"class": "timeDistance"})
for name in nameList:
 print(name. get_text())
nameList = bsObj. findAll("li", {"class": "essential trainer"})
for name in nameList:
 print(name. get_text())
nameList = bsObj. findAll("li", {"class": "first essential comment"})
for name in nameList:
 print(name. get_text())
nameList = bsObj. findAll("div", {"class": "resultsBlockFooter"})
for name in nameList:
 print(name. get_text())
```

Comment: Please can you mark my answer as correct, or comment on how to improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to iterate over the result blocks. Slightly different tags, but essentially the same thing. I use inspect element feature in Chrome, makes HTML scraping easy.

```
from urllib import urlopen

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
baseURL = 'http://www.gbgb.org.uk/resultsMeeting.aspx?id=135488'
html = urlopen(baseURL)
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
nameList = bsObj.findAll("div", {"class": "resultsBlock"})
for i in nameList:
    # just the trap info, the rest is similar
    nameList2 = i.findAll("li", {"class": "trap"})
    for j in nameList2:
        print(j.get_text())
```

Comment: Hi ncfirth,many thanks for you reply.I have run into a few problems though.Managed to get all the fields out as per your instructions but the loop rarely goes beyond the 7th or 8th race in the meeting(most meetings 12 or 14 races),and occasionally in the in the last race instead of 6 dogs there are only 4 or 5 that actually show.Also with some meetings I keep getting "Process finished with exit code 0".Sometimes if I refresh this will go away,but on some it doesn't I have tried looking for peculiarities in the source code round about the 7th or 8th race but it all seems the same..

Comment: If you have another question regarding using bs4 then I suggest you open another question, seems like the error might be more complex than this question.